# How do I input media query that removes fixed banner on the top and replaces it with mobile one?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a media query where I would like to have the original banner for desktop removed (i have used display: none;), and replaced by the banner for mobile uses.
Please refer to the code below:

```
<div class="headerContainer">
                            <img class="banner" src="web-banner.gif"/>
                            <img class="banner-phone" src="phone-img.jpg"/>
                        <div class="compLogo">
```

I am having some issues with inputing a media query that would remove the fixed position of the banner and replace it with the mobile one.
Apologies if I have skipped something, i am quite fresh to Web development.

```
.headerContainer {

                background-color:#000!important;
                border-bottom: 0 none;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                margin: 0 auto;
                max-width: 1000px;
                padding: 0 1%;
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                z-index: 100;
                height: 110px!important;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can have 2 banners at all times, and using a media query change their respective `display: ` properties. If you go mobile first, you can have the `display: block` on your mobile banner div and `display: none` on the normal banner, and when the screen size changes just change the display properties. Easy as that

Comment: What problem are you having and where is your media query that you are trying... please add a code example using codepen or jsfiddle and define your problem properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two media queries, one to set `position:fixed` for desktop an one for mobile devices:

```
.headerContainer {
  background-color:#000!important;
  border-bottom: 0 none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  padding: 0 1%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 110px!important;
}

/* media query sizes are only examples */
@media (min-width: 100px) {
  .headerContainer {
    position: absolute;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .headerContainer {
    position: fixed;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the phone banner to display:block whenever the width = 425px or less and also set display:none on the main banner. I've prepended .headerContainer to the mediaquery rules, so that these rules will have more specificity (which means that it will overrule the other rule).

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 425px){
    .headerContainer .banner {
        display: none;
    }
    .headerContainer .banner-phone {
        display: block;
    }
}

.banner {
  display: block;
}
.banner-phone {
  display: none;
}

.headerContainer {

            background-color:#000!important;
            border-bottom: 0 none;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0 auto;
            max-width: 1000px;
            padding: 0 1%;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 100;
            height: 110px!important;
}
```